# adding datepicker in 3rd party tooltip - part 2

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've asked a similar question before and got an answer that works in general, but not in my case. I will try to explain my question better here:

I have an external js library that I use to create tooltips. That's all the library does. 
I generate tooltip content dynamically depending on items the mouse hovers on. On this tooltip I use an input field to allow the user to choose a date via jquery datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/.

**The problem:**
The tooltip works in such a way that if the mouse goes out of the tooltip area, it will disappear. So when the mouse is moved to the datepicker, the tooltip is gone and only the date picker remains.

The way I create the tooltip contents is by concatenating some strings on the fly:
`content += 'test1' + '<input type="text" id="datepicker" >';`

Then I display the third party tooltip by calling:
`tooltip.pop(callerContainer, content);`

I don't know how to attach the datepicker to the input field and add the **datepicker object** to **content string** variable.

**Tried Solutions:**
I tried a trick by calling a method to add the datepicker to the tooltip after the tooltip has been incorporated into the page's DOM:
`setTimeout(attachDatepicker(), 600)`
Where `attachDatepicker()` does this: `$("#datepicker").datepicker();`

I also tried do add an `onmouseover` to the input field:
`<input type="text" id="datepicker" onmouseover="attachDatepicker()">'`

The tooltip steals all mouse events so if I wanted to check if mouse was outside of some element I had to bind separately like this:
    $("#element_id").mouseleave(function () { ... });

**Results:**
The `setTimeout` way didn't work, but the `onmouseover` solution did work. It showed the datepicker and now I already described the issue I have with the tooltip disappearing when the user selects a date.

I'd also be ok with embedding the actual calendar widgets into the html of the tooltip, but so far I've been unable to do that because once the tooltip is displayed, I cannot change its dimensions (it doesn't expand if I add more  to its contents).

**Note:**
What I noticed in Chrome, is that if I make an input field of type Date, Chrome will automatically add a datepicker to the input field and, most importantly, moving the mouse on that datepicker does not cause the tooltip to disappear. I would like to mimic the behaviour of datepicker in Chrome in other browsers, like Firefox. I'm sure it can be done becuase Chrome does it - I just don't have the knowledge. (I know why Chrome handles Date fields like this, so that's not my concern.)

Here is an example of what I'm trying to make - it looks like this in Chrome (with Chrome auto adding of a date picker to Date input fields) and as you can see the moving the mouse to the datepicker does not make the tooltip (datepicker parent container if you will) go away: [image: Chrome auto handling of Date type input fields - I want to make this]

The question is how to make a tooltip to which I can add a datepicker and be able to choose a date without having the tooltip close while choosing the date (while the mouse is away from tooltip container, but is on a child of the container)

**EDIT:**
jsfiddle now located at: http://jsfiddle.net/yad6L/14/
(Datepicker doesn't even load there - I added 2 jquery js files)

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle example

Comment: @Dom I use an external js class to make the tooltip. Is it possible to upload the js file into jsfiddle? I apologize if this sounds stupid, but I don't work with js much

Comment: Not stupid :) if it's external link, use `External Resources` on left hand side.